# Vim - remove a file from quickfix

Tags: vim

Say I have 10 lines in quickfix coming from 3 files: 1.txt, 2.txt, and 3.txt.

```
1.txt - 3 lines
2.txt - 3 lines
3.txt - 4 lines
```

What I'd like to do is to set up a binding that would remove all entries from file under cursor from quickfix. I use Cfilter plugin, but it requires more typing, so at first I'd have to yank needed file name, and then run `:Cfilter! <filename>`, which is not very convenient.

Any ideas on how better to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:help c_ctrl-r_ctrl-f` to insert the filename under the cursor.

With it, your command:

```
:Cfilter! foo/bar/baz.txt<CR>
```

can become:

```
:Cfilter! <C-r><C-f><CR>
```

which can be mapped for convenience:

```
" in after/ftplugin/qf.vim
nnoremap <buffer> <key> :Cfilter! <C-r><C-f><CR>
```

All you have to do is move the cursor on an entry from the file you don't want and press `<key>`.